# How to get the exact color of the blue navlist bar?

Tags: r, shiny

How to get the exact color in the below screenshot? I need it because I want to align some other colors with it.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "MWE",
  tabPanel(
    "some tab",
    navlistPanel(
      "Table of contents",
      tabPanel("first"),
      tabPanel("second"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Screenshot, paste to Gimp, use pipette: `0x337ab7` you dont need the screenshot, you already posted the picture you can use.